# Why Spring cloud works in network_mode: "host" and get Connection refused on bridge?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm starting with Spring cloud and docker and I'm trying dockerizing that. When I put network_mode: "host" in my docker-compose file the zuul gateway discovers the eureka server. But I need keep they in bridge and I'm getting connection refused.

My files are bellow:

```
Eureka Properties
spring:
  application:
    name: ecommerce-server
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      default-zone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/ecommerce}
```

```
Zuul Gateway Properties:

server:
  port: 8000
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/ecommerce}
```

```
Dockerfile Eureka:
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

```
Dockerfile Gateway:

FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

```
Docker-Compose
version: "3.8"
services:
    eureka-server:
        build: 
            context: ./ecommerce-consist-server/
        image: e-commerce-server
        networks:
            - my_net
        environment:
            - JAVA_OPTS=
                -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://eureka-server:8761/ecommerce/
                -Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/var/config-data

    gateway:
        build:
            context: ./ecommerce-consist-gateway/
        image: e-commerce-gateway
        networks:
            - my_net
        environment:
            - JAVA_OPTS=
                -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://eureka-server:8761/ecommerce/
                -Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/var/config-data
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - eureka-server
networks:
    my_net:
        driver: bridge
```

Someone can help solve this?